# VS-Code: OmniSharp Language Server is running, but no auto-suggestions show up (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

I am working with **VS-Code**. I installed the **C# extension**, which includes **OmniSharp** and created a simple **dotnet console project** via command line with `dotnet new console`.

The little flame in the left buttom corner of VS-Code says, "**OmniSharp Server is running**".

I wanted to start writing code, but **code suggestions won't show up**. I set up a little example where i use the `Math` Class of C#. But when I try to use methods of `Math` (for example `Math.Pow`), only some weird **standard suggestions** show up.
It looks like following:
[Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nn9Z.png)

When i fully write down the method, it actually gives me the **parameter description** ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/relle.png)), but what i want is, to have a **full list of methods** popping up, when using a class.

I edited my **settings.json** like [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_settings), but nothing changed.

Everything else like building or running this project works just fine.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am7oJ.png) is the output of my **OmniSharp Log** after using `Math.Pow`:

Answer (score 1):

After trying for hours a simple downgrade of the C# extension in VS-Code worked for me. I downgraded to v1.23.0.

Comment: That actually was the only thing that worked for me, thanks!